# Entity Framework Detaching a large collection of objects efficiently, and resolvingThe ObjectContext instance has been disposed can can no longer be

Tags: entity-framework, lazy-loading, dbcontext, eager-loading, detach

Our company has a software application that uses

-Entity Framework 4

-Code First approach

[image]

In our Data Access Layer code, we have instances of our Entity Framework Database context:

```
public class DataAccessLayer
{
    protected DbContext _context;
    public List<Task> GetSpecificProjectTasks(int projectIdInQuestion)
    {
        _context.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
        List<Task> taskList =
            (from tsk in _context.Tasks
             join prj in _context.Projects on prj.ID_Project 
             equals tsk.ParentID_Project
             select tsk).ToList();

        _context.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = true;
        return taskList;
    }
}
```

Now let's say some client code does the following:

```
List<Task> crazyTaskList = null;

using (DataAccessLayer dal = new DataAccessLayer())
{
    crazyTaskList  = dal.GetSpecificProjectTasks(5);
}

foreach (Task tsk in crazyTaskList)
{

}
```

The client code's `foreach` loop throws an error because `crazyTaskList` is `null`, and it gives me the error `The ObjectContext instance has been disposed can can no longer be used for operations that require a connection`. Why is it still `null`? I already temporarily turned off lazy loading so why is it `null`? Moreover, if I have to detach a huge list containing many objects of type `Task`, it would be really inefficient to write some kind of loop like the following:

```
public List<Task> GetSpecificProjectTasks(int projectIdInQuestion)
{ 
    _context.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
    List<Task> taskList =
        (from tsk in _context.Tasks join prj in _context.Projects
        on prj.ID_Project equals tsk.ParentID_Project 
        select tsk).ToList();

    // The following loop is inefficent
    for(int i = 0; i < taskList.Count(); i++)
    {
        dbContext.Entry(taskList[i]).State = EntityState.Detached;
    }

    _context.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = true;
    return taskList;
}
```

Comment: If you move the last brace for the using to AFTER the foreach loop, what happens?

Comment: I prefer Not to keep the Entity Framework context open for too long.  I just want the entities and/or list of entities to be detached.

Comment: Thats fine, but does it work.   What do you see on ToList in your dal method, whats materialised?

Comment: Turning off lazy loading does not automatically eager load. To ensure that all related entities are loaded you need to .Include() them prior to leaving the scope of the DB context. Detaching and returning entities is simply more trouble than it is ever worth. You will be far better off using a .Select() for the entity details and any related details into a simpler, purpose-build DTO/ViewModel to be consumed. (No Includes necessary)

Answer (score 0):

The best Idea is use POCO models for store information.

```
List<Task> taskList =
        (from tsk in _context.Tasks join prj in _context.Projects
        on prj.ID_Project equals tsk.ParentID_Project 
        select new TaskPOCO{ParentID_Project = tsk.ParentID_Project,....}).ToList();
```

Much more easiest way is use include for load all data under initial request

```
using     List<Task> taskList =
        (from tsk in _context.Tasks join prj in _context.Projects
        on prj.ID_Project equals tsk.ParentID_Project 
        select tsk).Include(t=>t.NavigationProperty).ToList();
```